# <rich:popupPanel buttons not working in JSF Project

Tags: java, spring, jsf, richfaces

In my JSF+Spring project i tried to add form and get values from popup window.but when buttons clicked then no debug point goes to relevant controller & also function not worked.
here shows my .xhtml file

please refer that and advice me to sort out this issue

thanks all...

```
    <h:outputLink value="#" id="ll">
        <rich:componentControl event="click" operation="show" target="lp">
            <a4j:param name="event" value="event" noEscape="true" />
            <rich:hashParam>
                <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="top" value="200" />
                <a4j:param noEscape="true" name="left" value="200" />
            </rich:hashParam>
        </rich:componentControl>
        Tag SAM
    </h:outputLink>
        <rich:popupPanel id="lp" modal="false" height="300" width="500" autosized="false" resizeable="true">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="SAM Selector" />
        </f:facet>

                <a4j:commandButton value="Load SAM" action="#{pOSController.loadSamPosTagging()}" render=" #{rich:clientId('dataTableSamView')}" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="Save Tagging" action="#{pOSController.saveSamPosTagging()}" render=" #{rich:clientId('dataTableSamView')}" />

                <rich:dataTable style="width:80%;" rows="10" value="#{pOSController.selectedSamBeans}" var="samView" id="dataTableSamView">

                    <rich:column style="height:25px;">
                        <f:facet name="header" />
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{samView.selected}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="true" itemLabel="" />
                            <a4j:ajax immediate="true" execute="@this" />
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">SAM UID</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{samView.samUid}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">SAM DID</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{samView.samDid}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Expire Date</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{samView.expireDate}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{samView.status}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:dataTable>
            <h:outputLink onclick="#{rich:component('lp')}.hide(event); return false;" value="#">SAM Tag</h:outputLink>
        </rich:popupPanel>
        <!--    ###################################################### Custom POPUP_PANEL ################################################################   -->                     
        </rich:column>              
    </rich:dataTable>
```

Please refer this link i added code in github
[GITHUB LINK - Click here](https://gist.github.com/priyankahdp/44a369e3723f50a38ceb)

Comment: I don't see an `<h:form/>` anywhere. Where is the form?

Comment: What means `</rich:column>` and `</rich:dataTable>` after `</rich:popupPanel>`? Is your popupPanel inside datatable?

Comment: @kolossus; dear kolossus..i adde form tags then imported src for jsf  file

Comment: @VasilLukach : dear Vasil i added datatable inside the popupPanel

Comment: Your popup panel should be outside of any datatable (optionally outside main form if you have form inside popup)

Comment: @VasilLukach : refer this dear friend
https://gist.github.com/priyankahdp/44a369e3723f50a38ceb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VasilLukach thanks.

Issue was with my parent page's datatable. I added popup separately from them.